# Cannot create symfony service

Tags: symfony

I have created a service in my custom bundle in service.yml, which requires EntityManager and two values from parameters.yml.

Example from my service.yml:

```
services:
    google.analytics.manager:
        class: CMS\AdminDashboardBundle\Manager\GoogleAnalytics\GoogleAnalyticsManager
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager','%ga.client.id%','%ga.key.name%']
```

I have this file included with DependcyInjection. But so far Symfony still telling me that this call

```
$this->get('google.analytics.manager')
```

cannot find my service. This service is a helper in this bundle (so not the bundle class). This bundle is correctly set in the AppKernel. So is there something I've missed?

Thanks

Comment: Where are you calling `$this->get(...)`? In a controller, another service, a listener, etc?

Comment: Have you imported the service.yml in config.yml file?

Comment: OP says the file is included with Dependency Injection, I assume using the `YamlFileLoader` in `CMS\AdminDashboardBundle\DependancyInjection\CMSAdminDashboardExtension.php`. If not, it's a good place to look PriaBrock.

Comment: Might also try the ever popular deleting of the cache.

Comment: Might as well try `$this->container->get('google.analytics.manager')` while you're at it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's is called from the controller. To make this work, I had to import it directly, but that is something I want to avoid. This service.yml is included in the CMS\AdminDashboardBundle\DependcyInjection\CMSAdminDashboardBundleExtension.php.

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $configuration = new Configuration();
    $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

    $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
    $loader->load('services.yml');
}
```

This should be done by Symfony.

Comment: Could you please mark your answer as accepted, so other people are aware of this as resolved? Thanks